# Don't submit existing values in MYSQL database using JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, html, validation

I have a HTML text field where I'm adding unique values to my database. At the moment I'm using PHP to validate that the value entered in the text field does not already exist in my database. I wonder if this is possible to achieve with JavaScript so that I can prevent the form from submitting if there is an error.

**EDIT: This is how I've come so far**

The JavaScript is executed in the form-tag by onsubmit="return validateForm()". I get the "System Error!" message and the form is submitted even though I say it should not.

```
function validateForm(){

    // Get all elements with the required-class 
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName('required');

    var submitForm = true;

    for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++){

        // Fetch input
        var input = x[i];

        // Fetch input value
        var inputValue = input.value;

        if(input.disabled == false){

            // Check if the value exist             
            if(inputValue == null || inputValue == ''){

                // Red border
                input.style.borderColor = "#ff0000";

                // Don't submit the form
                submitForm = false;

            } else if(input.name == 'company'){

                $.ajax({

                    type: 'GET',
                    url: '../includes/ajax_mysql.php?company='+input.value,
                    success: function(data){

                        if(data == '1'){ submitForm = false; } else{ submitForm = true; }

                        alert(data);

                    },
                    error: function(data){

                        submitForm = false;

                        alert("System Error!");

                    }

                });

            }

        }

    }

    if(!submitForm){ return false; } else{ return true; }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot access the DB directly through Javascript.

It's not possible to access the database directly through Javascript. The solution is to use AJAX to call a server-side PHP page which then queries the database.

Comment: Seems like the best solution for me. Can't get it to work though so updated my question with some code.

Comment: Solved it. I had to add `async: false` to set variables in the success/error function. Marking your answer as correct because it lead me to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript running on the client can only know what is in the database if you make an HTTP request to a server side program which interrogates the database.

You could do this using [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest), but it may not be worth the effort (since you'll then have to resubmit the data if it is OK).

Answer (score 0):

you cannot directly use JavaScript for accessing database as it is only a client side scripting language which can validate data only at the time you enter in the form , it can be done with server side scripting language like asp.net, php. You better use AJAX it can help you achieve your goal. Try it if you cant do ask where you go wrong

Answer (score 0):

your html text field

```
<input type="text" name="txt_field" id="txt_field">
<input type="submit" name="insert_value" id="insert_value" value="Send" />
```

now put js file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

now your script

```
$("#insert_value").live('click',function(){
    var keyword=$("#txt_field").val();
    $.ajax({
       url      : 'ajax.php',//page where you need to write the query
       type     : 'POST',    // wil get data as post
       data     : { 'keyword':keyword },//you need to get the data as $_POST['keyword'] in ajax page
       success  : function(resp){
            if(resp == "1")
            {
                alert("already exists"); 
            }
            else
            {
                //submit the form
            }
       },
       error    : function(resp){
            alert("System Error !!!");
       }
    });
});
```

in ajax page write the query and return like

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0)
{
    echo "1";
}
else
{
    echo "0";
}
```

try this and let me know the status.

Comment: <insert annoying *mysql_* is deprecated comment here>

Comment: Can't get it to work in my example as I use the onsubmit action in the form. Updated my question with the code I have so far.